# Create image from NSArray data

Tags: image, uiimage, nsarray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create image from RGB data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235991/create-image-from-rgb-data)

Ok I don't know if this can be done, but if so, awesome! I have an array of data values ranging from 0 to 255 for 100 objects. I want to make a 10x10 greyscale image from this and load it into a UIimage. Can this be done?